# neo4j cost high cpu usage, how can I know what was it work on?

Tags: neo4j

The neo4j's CPU usage remains 300%~600%, but I can not find out what application is use neo4j in these time. How to debug it? How can I know what applications are using the neo4j?

### My system is Ubuntu, 64G memory, 8 core.

### Neo4j Version: community-3.3.1

### Neo4j Store Sizes:

```
Array Store         5.82 GiB

Logical Log         57.14 MiB

Node Store          371.85 MiB

Property Store  10.89 GiB

Relationship Store  1.95 GiB

String Store    21.19 MiB

Total Store Size    24.57 GiB
```

### Neo4j memory config:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=16g

dbms.memory.heap.max_size=16g

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=16g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enterprise edition you can enable [query logging](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/query-logging/), and enable the options which break down time spent between planning, cpu execution, and waiting (such as on locks).

Enterprise edition also offers means to inspect (and if needed, to kill) running queries. Here's the [query management documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/query-management/).